# Call-graph profilers in Python

Tags: python, profiling

In my python program i have used a lot of modules and am trying to have a count of the functions called and the call chains involved. Is there a tool/module in python which will provide me with these statistics.

Comment: Are you really asking "How can I find the bottlenecks in my python code so that I can make it run faster"?

Comment: well at some levels yes . Its just that if the call chain of functions for a particular event is pretty long , then i would rather substitute with an efficient alternative method if i can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used this. It didn't work for my purposes since my app has many threads running at once and and I ended up with 12000 links and graphviz couldn't compile it. But it worked when I ran it on a single thread.

http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/

Answer (score 3):

pydoc -k profile

will give you a list of what's on your system. I've used profile and cProfile.

It's as easy as:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 if PROFILING:
  import cProfile
  cProfile.run("main()")
 else:
  main()
```

Comment: i diid try that earlier .. and i get error , thats why i was searching for a tool/module which will make it easier for me

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    cProfile.run("main()")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 36, in run
    result = prof.print_stats(sort)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 80, in print_stats
    import pstats
ImportError: No module named pstats

Comment: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/01/importerror-no-module-named-pstats-error-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Six years later I have the same question, some [people recommend](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2015/guide-to-python-profiling-cprofile-concrete-case-carbonara) to use KCachegrind for visualizing call chains. While it is a valid option for Linux users, it is extremely hard to install on Mac OSX and probably on Windows too.

Finally, I am using [gprof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot) instead. With just a few commands you will have your expressive call graph:

```
python -m cProfile -o output.pstats path/to/your/script arg1 arg2
gprof2dot.py -f pstats output.pstats | dot -Tpng -o output.png
```

Easy tool, fast results: check it out: https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot

**Edit:**

Now I found out you can get *KCachegrind* also via brew: `brew install qcachekrind`